# Entity Framework with dll files in C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dll

I am new to entity framework. I am creating a module that have to interact with database. The module will be general so it can be referenced in different projects. As those projects will have different databases so the confusion is that how I will get reference to that database in my library as it is going to be different each time?

For explaining purpose, if I shall be using sqlConnection then it will like

```
class myClass
{
   SqlConnection con;
   public myClass(SqlConnection con)
   {
       this.con=con;
   }

   public DataTable DoSomething()
   {
       try
       {
           connection.open();
           using (SqlDataAdapter com= new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from table1",con))
           {
               DataTable temp = new DataTable();
               com.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
               com.Fill(temp);
               return temp;
           }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: I am confused. You are talking about EF, but your Code uses `SqlDataAdapter` and a `DataTable`. This has nothing to do with Entity Framework.

Comment: Why use ADO.net !!

Comment: @Marc I have used Sql Adapter to show what I want to achieve with  Entity Framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement [EF Code First](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx) in a Class Library Project. Each other project that uses the model will have a reference to that project. Since each project will have its own database then each project has to have its own connection string, you can place this in the **app.config** file. Entity framework will add something like the following to your app.config in your class library project:

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="Your Connection string" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

The only thing you have to do or at least what I did and worked for me is to add entity to your other projects and change your connection string for each one of those.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EF the database structure (data context) should be same (between shared projects), unless you are defining separate data contexts for each, your connection strings can be kept in a config file (for each individual project).